# Kohana routing - subfolders

Tags: php, routes, kohana

Hy.
I have 2 controllers, the first one *application/classes/controller/welcome.php* and the second one *application/classes/controller/admin/welcome.php*.

And I have the following routings, set in bootstrap.php

```
Route::set('admin', '(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))', array('directory' => '(admin)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

If I access *example.com/welcome* it calls *index* action from the *application/classes/controller/welcome.php* controller (this is good),
if I access *example.com/admin/welcome* it calls *index* action from *application/classes/controller/admin/welcome.php* controller (this is good),

but if I access simply *example.com*, it calls the admin's welcome and not the other one, and I can't understand why.

I want this: if I access *example.com*, then call *index* action from *application/classes/controller/admin/welcome.php* controller.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Excellent, glad to help :) If you could mark the question as answered then it'll make it easier for people searching for the problem in future to find a resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've set the directory tag in the first route to be optional, and so it's matching when no directory is specified. Try:

```
Route::set('admin', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('directory' => '(admin)'))
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

This should make the tag mandatory, and so it won't match on /.

Answer (score 0):

The routes you specify are matched from top to bottom: the first one that matches will be used. So, swap your routes and it should work (make the 'admin' route the last one).